# My MacBook refuses to switch tabs while I maximise my window. What can I do?

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook refuses to switch tabs while I maximise my window. What can I do?

I couldn't find any info on Google about this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What Mac model? What display are you using? What OS? Does this happen in every application, or just one?